# Method to check the existence of a Queue in RabbitMQ using node amqp library

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

We are trying to build a chat application with nodejs , rabbitmq and mongodb. For faster delivery of messages , we are using rabbitmq . Since I am new to this concept, if anybody can, kindly help me out. I am using the node amqp module to connect to the rabbitmq server(https://www.npmjs.org/package/amqp) .

I am declaring an exchange as given below :

var amqp = require('amqp');var amqpconnection = amqp.createConnection({host: 'localhost'});var exchange = amqpconnection.exchange('Exchange',{confirm:true,type:"direct", durable:true, autoDelete:false},function (exchange){});

I am publishing a message using the below method :

exchange.publish('receiver_queue', message ,{persistent: true,mandatory:true},function(data){console.log("Message Published");console.log(data);});

My question is , when I am publishing to a queue that already exists , in the publish callback , we get a 'false' response but when I am publishing to a queue that doesn't exist at all , in the publish callback , still we get a 'false' response ; Why is it so ? Is there any method by which I can check whether a queue exists before publishing to it ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be considered an anti pattern, ie: most messaging applications use a *fire and forget* style, where the publisher doesn't care about who receives the message.

Now, if you need to make sure the message gets routed to some queue, then you can use the `mandatory` flag when publishing the message.

To know if a queue exists, you can use `queue_declare`, but passing the `passive = true` flag when sending the queue.declare

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
connection.exchange('Exchange', {type: 'topic', confirm: true,passive:true},function(exchange) {
publish = exchange.publish(Queue, xml, { mandatory: false });
return true;
```

});

Comment: Can u please explain what you are trying to do in the above mentioned code ?

Comment: For your kind information, please find the below :                      The mandatory argument is by by default false. This flag tells the server how to react if the message cannot be routed to a queue. If this flag is set, the server will return an unroutable message with a Return method. If this flag is false, the server silently drops the message.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.